# Avoid pressing . (period) key to move to next field in DateTime picker control

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

In datetime picker control the user has to press .(period) to move to different fields (like day, month year)

I want to override this behaviour by allowing the user to enter date without entering .(period)

Is there any to achieve this programmatically in C# winforms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should be the alternative? Force leading zeroes for january and for days?

Comment: Its like if the date is 04/10/2010 the user should be able type just 04 10 2010 in the control.

Comment: Or do you want to specify the separator?  e.g. space, '/', '.'

Comment: No i dont want to specify any seperator. Once the user enter month the cursor should automatically move to day and then year

Comment: Or is there any event to capture the input from individual fields so that i can manually move to next field programmatically?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399954/datetimepicker-automatically-move-to-next-datepart/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not very beautiful code but you could of course send the `.` automatically.
Just handle the `ValueChanged` event (which will only be called when the user has entered a "whole" value for date part he's currently editing) and in the event handler you add the code `SendKeys.Send(".");`.