# Access Win32/MFC "Stuff" from C#

Tags: c#, .net, mfc

There's a great code sample in this post:

[DateTimePicker automatically move to next datepart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399954/datetimepicker-automatically-move-to-next-datepart)

which shows how to clean up some of the behavior of the DateTimePicker in .NET.  Unfortunately the code won't compile, since .NET can't understand the WM_KEYDOWN type stuff.  I was able to google and get values for a lot of the constants, like

WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

But I'm really stuck getting NMHDR  and  WM_REFLECT  to work.  Is there some sort of Win32 assembly I need to add to my project to get all of this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use what is known as [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx).

> [...] As an increasing developer base moves
>   its production applications to managed
>   code, it seems only natural that there
>   will be even more occasions for
>   developers to dip down into the
>   underlying operating system for some
>   critical tidbit of functionality—at
>   least for the time being. Thankfully,
>   the interop features of the common
>   language run-time (CLR), called
>   Platform Invoke (P/Invoke), are very
>   complete [...].

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html

```
private const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN        = 0x0100;
```

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/NMHDR.html

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
struct NMHDR 
{
   public IntPtr hwndFrom;
   public IntPtr idFrom;
   public int code;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Visit pinvoke.net for these declarations.  Or use the [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120).